# how to get json_query display property name in ansible playbook

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath, json-query

I have this json block as an example:

```
"msg": {
        "10.10.28.10": {
            "core": 23,
            "cpuCoreUsage": 0.0,
            "cputhreshold": 80,
            "status": "healthy",
            "status_code": 0,
            "status_reason": "Checks passed",
            "timestamp": 1614281443,
            "total": 0
        },
        "10.10.28.5": {
            "core": 18,
            "cpuCoreUsage": 2.0,
            "cputhreshold": 80,
            "status": "healthy",
            "status_code": 0,
            "status_reason": "Checks passed",
            "timestamp": 1614281443,
            "total": 0
        },
        "capacity": 1080
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get this output with property name and status to look like something like this.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT:
IP: 10.10.28.5, status: healthy, status_code: 0
IP: 10.10.28.10, status: healthy, status_code: 0
```

I can print everything except the IP part with this:

```
  - name: STATUS QUERY
    debug:
      msg: "code: {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ data.json | json_query(status_code_query) | list }}"
    vars:
            status_code_query: "*.{statuscode: status_code, status: status}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use JMESPath for this, the reason is, although it is pretty good at querying JSON, it is not really good at displaying JSON keys.

The [`keys()`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys) function is the closest you can find there, but it will yield you an array and since you cannot come back to a parent node you cannot do something like:

```
*.{IP: keys($)[0], statuscode: status_code, status: status}
```

Although this is a pretty frequently requested feature: https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.js/issues/22

---

Now to solve your use case, you can use the [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) function, but the one of Python.

You also have a issue in the fact that all your values of `data.json` are not dictionaries: in `"capacity": 1080`, the value is a simple `int`.

You can go work around this odd data structure using a `when` test and verify if you value is indeed a [`mapping`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#mapping) (or in other words a dictionary).

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: >-
          IP: {{ item }}, 
          status: {{ data.json[item].status }}, 
          status_code: {{ data.json[item].status_code }}
      loop: "{{ data.json.keys() }}"
      when: data.json[item] is mapping
      vars:
        data:
          json:
            10.10.28.10:
              core: 23
              cpuCoreUsage: 0
              cputhreshold: 80
              status: healthy
              status_code: 0
              status_reason: Checks passed
              timestamp: 1614281443
              total: 0
            10.10.28.5:
              core: 18
              cpuCoreUsage: 2
              cputhreshold: 80
              status: healthy-
              status_code: 0-
              status_reason: Checks passed
              timestamp: 1614281443
              total: 0
            capacity: 1080
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.10.28.10) => {
    "msg": "IP: 10.10.28.10,  status: healthy,  status_code: 0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.10.28.5) => {
    "msg": "IP: 10.10.28.5,  status: healthy-,  status_code: 0-"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=capacity) 

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

This said, it is also a perfect use case for the [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) filter:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: >-
          IP: {{ item.key }}, 
          status: {{ item.value.status }}, 
          status_code: {{ item.value.status_code }}
      loop: "{{ data.json | dict2items }}"
      when: item.value is mapping
      vars:
        data:
          json:
            10.10.28.10:
              core: 23
              cpuCoreUsage: 0
              cputhreshold: 80
              status: healthy
              status_code: 0
              status_reason: Checks passed
              timestamp: 1614281443
              total: 0
            10.10.28.5:
              core: 18
              cpuCoreUsage: 2
              cputhreshold: 80
              status: healthy-
              status_code: 0-
              status_reason: Checks passed
              timestamp: 1614281443
              total: 0
            capacity: 1080
```

Would yield the same recap.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I get this error: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'int object' has no attribute 'status_code' I use this instead of your vars: 
- name: GET HEALTH CHECK 
uri: url: http://{{ ansible_fqdn }}:8888/healthcheck 
method: GET 
return_content: yes 
status_code: 200 
body_format: json 
validate_certs: no 
register: data 
- debug: msg: >- IP: {{ item }}, 
status_code: {{ data.json[item].status_code }} 
loop: "{{ data.json.keys() }}" '''

Comment: Means `data.json[item]` is not a dictionary like your provided it in your question. Debug it to see what it give and edit it in your question: `-debug: var=data.json`

Comment: I added my debug output as an answer.

Comment: You should have [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66375540/edit) your question rather

Comment: This said, I edited the answer to cover your issue.

Comment: thanks works like a charm! You're a life saver!

Comment: @confusedjoe I also have a less cumbersome idea included now, if you're ever interested.

Comment: yes I'm interested, can you please share your idea?